# Ruby arrays if statement and && operator error?

Tags: ruby

My code:

```
a=["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo" ]

if a.include?"Hel" && a.include?"lo"
puts "#{a[1,4].join}"
end
```

irb returns syntax error. Help!

Answer (score 2):

Write as below to remove the error :-

```
a = ["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo" ]

if a.include?("Hel") && a.include?("lo") # <- look the change here
  puts "#{a[1,4].join}"
end
```

The way you wrote is not a valid Ruby code.

Comment: It returns Hel63lo instead of Hello ? Why is that?

Comment: @user3222947 because it's range: get me element from 1 to 4.

Comment: @DarekNędza i fixed it like this: "#{a[1] + a[4]}". Is there a short/succinct way of doing this?

Comment: @user3222947 Well, you don't have to put it into string and interpolate it. `join` returns string already: `puts [arr[1],arr[4]].join`.